# ProducerFencedException: There is a newer producer with the same transactionalId which fences the current one

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a single instance Kafka Streams application consuming from a topic with one partition. I have recently enabled `EXACTLY_ONCE_V2` as processing guarantee and I'm now experiencing consistently occuring error messages stating

> stream-thread [my_app-513c73a3-44f5-4542-85d7-542f57938625-StreamThread-1] task [1_0] Error encountered sending record to topic my_app-suppress-state-store-v1-changelog for task 1_0 due to:
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
> Written offsets would not be recorded and no more records would be sent since the producer is fenced, indicating the task may be migrated out

How do I prevent this error message from showing up? Are some of my configurations wrong?

My Streams setup is

```kotlin
val props = Properties()
    props["bootstrap.servers"] = appConfig.bootstrapServers
    props[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG] = appConfig.applicationId
    props[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = Serdes.String()::class.java
    props[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG] = SpecificAvroSerde::class.java
    props[StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG] =
        LogAndContinueExceptionHandler::class.java
    props[StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG] = -1
    props[StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG] = StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE_V2
    props[AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG] = appConfig.schemaRegistry
    return props
```

and my topology looks like

```kotlin
 builder.stream(
        topicSerdeConfig.inputTopic,
        Consumed.with<String, CorridorFlow>(Topology.AutoOffsetReset.LATEST)
            .withKeySerde(topicSerdeConfig.stringKeySerde)
            .withValueSerde(topicSerdeConfig.inputValueSerde)
    )
        .peek { _, value -> logReceivedRecord(value) }
        .filter { key, value -> hasKeyAndValue(key, value) }
        .process(suppressProcessorSupplier, suppressProcessorStoreName)
        .process(corridorToBiddingZoneProcessorSupplier)
        .peek { _, value -> logPublishingRecord(value) }
        .to(
            topicSerdeConfig.outputTopic,
            Produced.with(topicSerdeConfig.stringKeySerde, topicSerdeConfig.outputValueSerde, CustomPartitioner())
        )
```

It is the `SuppressProcessor` which causes the error message. Pseudocode for the processor is

```kotlin
class SuppressProcessor() {

  // Initialize context and get state store

  fun process(record) {
    // store each received record in state store
    // if all expected records are received forward records
    // commit
  }

  fun schedule() {
   // every hour, loop through all stored records and delete the expired ones
  }

}
```

Note that the processor receives around 10 records as a batch every 10 seconds. Usually, all the expected records are sent in the same bunch.